# How to append group row into dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, append, rbind

I have this df1:

```
A B C
1 2 3
5 7 9
```

where `A B C` are columns names.

I have another df2 with one column:

```
A
1
2
3
4
```

I would like to append df2 for each column of df1, creating this final dataframe:

```
A B C 
1 2 3
5 7 9
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data.frame(sapply(df1, c, unlist(df2)), row.names = NULL)
#  A B C
#1 1 2 3
#2 5 7 9
#3 1 1 1
#4 2 2 2
#5 3 3 3
#6 4 4 4
```

**DATA**

```
df1 = structure(list(A = c(1L, 5L), B = c(2L, 7L), C = c(3L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 = structure(list(A = 1:4), .Names = "A", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: `unlist(df2, use.names = FALSE)` might be more efficient than `row.names = NULL`

Answer (score 10):

We can replicate `df2` for the number of columns of `df1`, unname it, then `rbind` it.

```
rbind(df1, unname(rep(df2, ncol(df1))))
#   A B C
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 5 7 9
# 3 1 1 1
# 4 2 2 2
# 5 3 3 3
# 6 4 4 4
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 5L), B = c(2L, 7L), C = c(3L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df2 <- structure(list(A = 1:4), .Names = "A", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `unname`, yes, that's what I was trying to think of to make `rbind` work more easily. +1.

Answer (score 7):

We can use `base R` methods

```
rbind(df1, setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, rep(list(df2$A), 3))), names(df1)))
#  A B C
#1 1 2 3
#2 5 7 9
#3 1 1 1
#4 2 2 2
#5 3 3 3
#6 4 4 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 5L), B = c(2L, 7L), C = c(3L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = 1:4), .Names = "A", class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a base R method with `rbind`, `rep`, and `setNames`:

```
rbind(dat, setNames(data.frame(rep(dat1, ncol(dat))), names(dat)))
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 5 7 9
3 1 1 1
4 2 2 2
5 3 3 3
6 4 4 4
```

Edit: turns out`data.frame` isn't necessary:

```
rbind(dat, setNames(rep(dat1, ncol(dat)), names(dat)))
```

will work.

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(A = c(1L, 5L), B = c(2L, 7L), C = c(3L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

dat1 <-
structure(list(A = 1:4), .Names = "A", row.names = c(NA, -4L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 7):

I just love R, here is yet another `Base R` solution but with `mapply`:

```
data.frame(mapply(c, df1, df2))
```

**Result:**

```
  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 5 7 9
3 1 1 1
4 2 2 2
5 3 3 3
6 4 4 4
```

**Note:**

No need to deal with colnames like almost all the other solutions... The key to why this works is that "`mapply` calls FUN for the values of ... [each element]
 (re-cycled to the length of the longest...[element]" (See `?mapply`). In other words, `df2$A` is recycled to however many columns `df1` has.

**Data:**

```
df1 = structure(list(A = c(1L, 5L), B = c(2L, 7L), C = c(3L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
                                                                               "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df2 = structure(list(A = 1:4), .Names = "A", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6):

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1,5),
                  B=c(2,7),
                  C=c(3,9))
df2 <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Solution:

```
df2 <- matrix(rep(df2$A, ncol(df1)), ncol=ncol(df1))
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)
rbind(df1,df2)
```

Result:

> ```
>   A B C
> 1 1 2 3
> 2 5 7 9
> 3 1 1 1
> 4 2 2 2
> 5 3 3 3
> 6 4 4 4
> ```

Answer (score 5):

By analogy with @useR's excellent Base R answer, here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(purrr)

map2_df(df1, df2, c)
```

> ```
>   A B C
> 1 1 2 3
> 2 5 7 9
> 3 1 1 1
> 4 2 2 2
> 5 3 3 3
> 6 4 4 4
> ```

Here are a few other (less desirable) options from when I first answered this question.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2 %>% mutate(B=A, C=A))
```

Or, if we want to dynamically get the number of columns and their names from df1:

```
bind_rows(df1,
          df2[,rep(1,ncol(df1))] %>% setNames(names(df1)))
```

And one more Base R method:

```
rbind(df1, setNames(df2[,rep(1,ncol(df1))], names(df1)))
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution from `purrr`, which uses `map_dfc` to loop through all columns in `df1` to combine all the elements with `df2$A`.

```
library(purrr)

map_dfc(df1, ~c(., df2$A))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
      A     B     C
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     3
2     5     7     9
3     1     1     1
4     2     2     2
5     3     3     3
6     4     4     4
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 5L), B = c(2L, 7L), C = c(3L, 9L)), .Names = c("A", 
                                                                               "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(A = 1:4), .Names = "A", class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is `data.table` approach which doesn't require to handle column names:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, c, df2$A)]
```

> ```
>    A B C
> 1: 1 2 3
> 2: 5 7 9
> 3: 1 1 1
> 4: 2 2 2
> 5: 3 3 3
> 6: 4 4 4
> ```

Note that the OP has described `df2` to consist only of one column.

There is also a base R version of this approach:

```
data.frame(lapply(df1, c, df2$A))
```

> ```
>   A B C
> 1 1 2 3
> 2 5 7 9
> 3 1 1 1
> 4 2 2 2
> 5 3 3 3
> 6 4 4 4
> ```

This is similar to [d.b's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043472/3817004) approach but doesn't required to deal with column names.