# Replicating a column and concatenating the result with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There's an interesting [trending question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043445/how-to-append-group-row-into-dataframe) in [r](/questions/tagged/r), it goes like this:

> I have this df1:
>
> ```
> A B C
> 1 2 3
> 5 7 9
> ```
>
> where `A B C` are columns names.
>
> I have another df2 with one column:
>
> ```
> A
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```
>
> I would like to append df2 for each column of df1, creating this final
>   dataframe:
>
> ```
> A B C 
> 1 2 3
> 5 7 9
> 1 1 1
> 2 2 2
> 3 3 3
> 4 4 4
> ```
>
> is it possible to do it?

I was wondering, how would this be done in Pandas?

---

<sub>I've posted my own solution below, but I'm also looking for other, better alternatives!</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`apply`

```
df1.apply(pd.Series.append, to_append=df2.A)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  5  7  9
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
```

---

**Option 2**
`numpy.vstack` and `numpy.tile`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack([df1, np.tile(df2, df1.shape[1])]),
    columns=df1.columns
)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  5  7  9
2  1  1  1
3  2  2  2
4  3  3  3
5  4  4  4
```

Comment: These are really nifty too.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

Using `np.repeat` and `df.append`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.values.repeat(len(df1.columns), axis=1),\
                                                  columns=df1.columns)
out = df1.append(df2)
out

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  5  7  9
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
```

---

**Option 2**

Using `pd.concat` and `df.append`

```
out = df1.append(pd.concat([df2.A] * len(df1.columns), 1, keys=df1.columns))
print(out)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  5  7  9
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
```

---

You can also use `pd.concat` for the second step, but `df.append` is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `pd.concat` and `ffill` with axis=1:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).ffill(1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  5  7  9
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
```

Comment: Oh! This is smart. Taking advantage of the fact that it produces NaNs.

Comment: I don't like the casting to float and having to recast as int.